# How to get current class instance and assign to final property by `this` in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, instance-variables

I followed this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter/) to learning Dart/Flutter. I tried to edit some source for making this code better.

```
class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<ChatMessageView> _chatMessageViewList = <ChatMessageView>[];
  final TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();

  final AnimationController _chatMessageAnimationController;

  bool _isComposing = false;

  ChatScreenState() {
    _chatMessageAnimationController = new AnimationController(
      duration: new Duration(microseconds: 700),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

...
}
```

I planned to reuse the instance of the AnimationController because I have to create it as much as list have. However, I can't use `this` keyword anyways. I understood this error message but I wonder that have any ways to assign `this` keyword to the final property of the current class?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`final` in

```
final AnimationController _chatMessageAnimationController;
```

and

```
_chatMessageAnimationController = ...
```

contradict each other. `final` on instance fields means it can only be initialized at object creation. This means before even the constructor body is executed.

You can only use

- constructor parameters like `this._chatMessageAnimationController`
- initializer lists `ChatScreenState() : _chatMessageAnimationController = ... {`
- field initializers `final AnimationController _chatMessageAnimationController = ...;`

to assign a value to such a field.
Unfortunately none of these methods allow you to reference `this` because object initialization is not completed yet.